# PHP returning static variable by reference

Tags: php, reference, static, return

Ignore the namespaces etc could any one explain why I can't return a reference to my static array? Effectively the class is a getter and setter. I wanted to use static methods as the class will never need to be instantiated again throughout the applications life cycle.

I understand what I'm doing might just be "bad practice" - any more knowledge on this matter would be appreciated.

```
namespace xtend\core\classes; 
use xtend\core\classes\exceptions;

class registry {

private static $global_registry = array();

private function __construct() {}

public static function add($key, $store) {
    if (!isset(self::$global_registry[$key])) {
        self::$global_registry[$key] = $store;
    } else {
        throw new exceptions\invalidParameterException(
            "Failed to add the registry. The key $key already exists."
        );
    }
}

public static function remove($key) {
    if (isset(self::$global_registry[$key])) {
        unset(self::$global_registry[$key]);
    } else {
        throw new exceptions\invalidParameterException(
            "Cannot remove key $key does not exist in the registry"
        );
    }
}

public static function &get($key) {
    if (isset(self::$global_registry[$key])) {
        $ref =& self::$global_registry[$key];
        return $ref;
    } else {
        throw new exceptions\invalidParameterException(
            "Cannot get key $key does not exist in the registry"
        );
    }
}

}
```

Using it like this

```
$test = array("my","array");
\xtend\core\classes\registry::add("config",&$test);
$test2 =& \xtend\core\classes\registry::get("config");
$test2[0] = "notmy";    
print_r($test);
```

Your would presume I would get back

```
array("notmy","array");
```

But I just get back the original.

Comment: you can access via registry::add($key, $store)

Comment: Are you using it correctly? See [php.net reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php)

Comment: @AlvinWong updated my question with how I am using it.

Comment: @JonathanTizard Perhaps you're not making `add` the right way: [Passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executive summary:

```
class Registry {
    private static $global_registry = array();

    public static function Add($key, &$value){
        static::$global_registry[$key] =& $value;
    }
    public static function &Get($key){
        return static::$global_registry[$key];
    }
    public static function Remove($key){
        unset(static::$global_registry[$key]);
    }
}

$test = array("my", "array");
Registry::Add("config", $test);
$test2 =& Registry::Get("config");
$test2[0] = "notmy";    
var_dump($test);
```

It's really quite simple once you understand how it works:

- **Firstly,** the `add` function must [pass by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), otherwise the value that is seen in the function isn't even the value that you have passed in.
- **Secondly,** when storing the value in `$global_registry`, we must [assign by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#language.operators.assignment.reference). Otherwise, the value stored isn't even the value seen in the function.
- **Thirdly,** we must [return by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) by putting an ampersand in the function declaration. You have already done this, except this code:

```
$ref =& self::$global_registry[$key]; // redundant line
return $ref;
```

Is the same as this code:

```
return self::$global_registry[$key];
```

Because in the line `public static function &get`, we have already declared that the return value is a reference.

- **And Lastly,** we need to assign the returned reference by reference, which you have also did:

```
$test2 =& Registry::Get("config");
```

As you can can see, the *whole chain* must be by reference. If any one of the step is not done by referece, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can return your static array by deferencing:

```
$ref = &self::$global_registry[$key];
```

You'll need to access it like this:

```
$keyVal = &registry::get($key);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use following code to workout for references

```
class Apple {

    public static $basket = [], $scripts =[];

    public static function addToBasket($grapes) {
        self::$scripts =& self::AppStatic(__CLASS__ . __METHOD__, array());
        self::$scripts[$grapes] = ['type' => $grapes];
        return self::$scripts;
    }

    public static function &AppStatic($name, $default_value = NULL) {
        if (isset(self::$basket[$name]) || array_key_exists($name, self::$basket)) {
            return self::$basket[$name];
        }

        if (isset($name)) {
            return self::$basket[$name] = &$default_value;
        }

        $data = NULL;
        foreach (self::$basket as $key => $value) {
            $data[$key] = $value;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```